# Vaadin Panel highlight on mouseover

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a set of Vaadin's Panels.

I need to highlight each panel component on mouse over event and release the highlighting on mouse out. Also on click I need to change the style of the component permanently to another.

Could you please show an example how it can be done in Vaadin ?

Comment: Use a stylesheet for this, with on mouse over events/styles

Comment: Add some JavaScript to your Panel classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As André pointed out, for the mouse over use `:hover` in your stylesheet and set the style with `setStyle("your-special-panel")`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) for a reference. For the change of the style after clicking, first add a ClickListener to the panel (`addClickListener(..)`). In that click listener you call `addStyle("style-class-clicked-panel")` which then references the style class in your style sheet for the clicked look.

In Java:

```
[...]
@Override
public void click(ClickEvent event){
    // handle the click event
    panel.addStyle("style-class-clicked-panel");
}
```

In Css:

```
.your-special-panel:hover {
    background-color: red;  /* style for on mouse */
}

.style-class-clicked-panel{
    background-color: yellow; /* style for clicked */
}
```